# jQuery to find element outside of current DOM not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I am prototyping a commenting system. As there will be multiple posts to comment on. I am testing this by inserting text when the button "Send comment is clicked". When this button is clicked, it should search the parent to find the empty comment

and append it with placeholder text, but it's not doing anything.

HTML

```
<form class="comment-box">
    <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here"></textarea>
    <span class="brand-color">0/400</span>
    <a class="btn submit-comment">Send comment</a>
</form>
<p class="empty-comment">

</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('.submit-comment').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('.empty-comment').append('comment inserted');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p27dLLss/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not a string, also `.empty-comment` is the next sibling of the parent.

```js
$('.submit-comment').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().next('.empty-comment').append('comment inserted');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="comment-box hide">
  <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here"></textarea>
  <span class="brand-color">0/400</span>
  <a class="btn right submit-comment">Send comment</a>
</form>
<p class="empty-comment">

</p>
```